# How to show/hide React components when clicking on a button that is in another component?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following React component:

```
export default class AdminHomePage extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <OptionsMenu />
        <Form /> // needs to be inittially hidden 
        <ImportFile /> // needs to be inittially hidden 
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

And inside my **OptionsMenu** component, I have two buttons:

```
export default class OptionsMenu extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="admin-menu">
        <div className="admin-menu-header">Select an option</div>
        <div className="buttons-admin-menu">

          <button className="button-admin">
            Register
          </button>

          <button className="button-admin" onClick={getFileModel}>
            Import CSV file
          </button>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

And initially I need to have both the **Form** and the **ImportFile** components hidden, so when I click on the "Import CSV" button that is INSIDE the **OptionsMenu** file, I show the **ImportFile** component, and when I click on the "Register" button, I show the **Form** component.

I've only found topics that show how to hide/show components that have its respective button on the same file/class, so I don't know how to deal with buttons and components on different classes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a method in the parent component that records state (state that determined visibility), and pass that method as a prop:

```
export default class AdminHomePage extends Component {

constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
      isVisible: false
   }
   this.isElVisible = this.isElVisible.bind(this);
}

isElVisible() {
   this.setState({isVisible: !isVisible});
}

render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <NavBar />
    <OptionsMenu isViz={this.isElVisible} />
    <Form /> // needs to be inittially hidden 
    { this.state.isVisible? <ImportFile /> : '' } // needs to be inittially hidden 
    <Footer />
  </div>
  );
  }

}
```

Then, call `props.isViz` in your `OptionsMenu` component, onClick or whenever you want it to be visible.

Comment: The code failed to compile. It says: 'isVisible' is not defined  - line this.setState({ isVisible: !isVisible });

Comment: @Caroline It was just a typo.. All you have to do is change `this.isVisible = this.isVisible.bind(this);` to `this.isElVisible = this.isElVisible.bind(this);` Anyways, your solution is basically exactly what I proposed... If your implementation isn't exactly the same, here on SO that is still considered a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks, @silencedogood. You helped me a lot, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem creating a function and then sending the function as a prop to the OptionsMenu component (similar to what @silencedogood said, but there were a few issues with his answer).

Component **AdminHomePage**:

```
export default class AdminHomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleFormClick = this.handleFormClick.bind(this);
    this.handleImportClick = this.handleImportClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      formVisible: false,
      importVisible: false,
    };
  }

  handleFormClick() {
    this.setState({
      formVisible: true,
      importVisible: false,
    });
  }

  handleImportClick() {
    this.setState({
      formVisible: false,
      importVisible: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar
          keycloak={this.props.keycloak}
          name={this.props.name}
          email={this.props.email}
        />
        <OptionsMenu
          showForm={this.handleFormClick}
          showImport={this.handleImportClick}
        />
        {this.state.formVisible ? <Form /> : null}
        {this.state.importVisible ? <HomePage /> : null}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Calling the function in the component **AdminHomePage**:

```
export default class OptionsMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="admin-menu">
        <div className="admin-menu-header">Selecione uma opção</div>
        <div className="buttons-admin-menu">
          <button
            className="button-admin"
            onClick={() => this.props.showForm()}
          >
            Register
          </button>
          <button
            className="button-admin"
            onClick={() => {
              this.props.showImport();
              getFileModelo();
            }}
          >
            Import CSV file
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```